# Add Google Chrome extensions to your browser cefsharp or any webbrowser

Tags: c#, .net, browser

Is there an example of adding plugins to Google IE browser that supports language c# or .net I want to run files js - json - hrml popup

Comment: What do you mean by Google IE browser?

Comment: I wanted to run the Google extension inside the Cefsharp browser or another browser I wanted an example of this

Answer (score 1):

CefSharp does support Chrome extensions. Here's an example in CefSharp's official repository: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/d6ca2531eb2d3502a865973e24c64b44fe274821

To load an extension, unzip it to a directory, implement `IExtensionHandler`, and load it like this:

```
requestContext.LoadExtensionsFromDirectory(dir, extensionHandler);
```

But it's not so simple. As you may know, CefSharp is based on Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF). In particular, it uses a so-called Alloy runtime within CEF. This runtime supports a very minimum of extension APIs, and most of the extensions won't work.

The good news is that CEF has another runtime: Chrome runtime. And CefSharp is working on adopting it. Check if this is something you can already use in this discussion: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/discussions/4123

Comment: I wrote a blog post describes which web view libraries support extensions and to which extent: https://dev.to/dotnetbrowser/chrome-extensions-in-net-web-view-controls-11lm

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft just released [Blazor](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/02/06/blazor-experimental-project/), which allows browsers to run Razor / C# code on the client side.  You could research and experiment with that.

However, you don't need that to run js - json - html popup.  Use something like ASP.Net MVC to run any C# code on the server.  The server generates your HTML and Javascript and stuff.  Browsers know how to work with all of that stuff without any plugins.

This site will work better when you have specific questions and you can show your code and what you have tried.  For a question like this, Google will work better for you!  Good luck.

Comment: I want to run Google extensions within the browser thanks for your attention anyway

Comment: I used this example but could not connect js-json-popup.html files

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do.  If you said you tried to work through an example but you are having a specific problem, then post your code and what is going wrong and you will get a better answer.  Meanwhile, feel free to run as many Google extensions as you would like - nobody is stopping you.

Comment: Use this example and try putting the Google extension appended with js-json html      https://github.com/sential/WebExpress